# Conversion from string "" to type 'Double' is not valid. in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, calculator

I'm completely new to programming in general, and I've decided to make a simple little calculator as my first project.

I've been getting "Conversion from string "" to type 'Double' is not valid." every time I click ButtonPlus.

Full code:
http://pastebin.com/JJxkg4fy

Near the bottom where I have the code for ButtonPlus, I'm trying to convert the text in TextBox1 to a double.
What's really confusing is that it doesn't happen when I try to divide.
When I press the divide button, nothing happens. :/

```
    Private Sub ButtonPlus_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ButtonPlus.Click
    If CInt(True) Then Val1 = CDbl(TextBox1.Text)
    Opperan = "+"
    TextBox1.Clear()
    Funct.Text = "+"
End Sub

Private Sub ButtonDivide_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ButtonPlus.Click
    If CInt(True) Then Val1 = CDbl(TextBox1.Text)
    Opperan = "/"
    TextBox1.Clear()
    Funct.Text = "÷"
End Sub
```

Comment: Why in the world do you have a `CInt(True)`?

Comment: Anyway, are you sure you've typed something in `TextBox1`? Also, giving them more meaningful names can help catch mistakes like accidentally dragging a `TextBox` onto your form twice, for example.

Comment: Nothing happens when you click `ButtonDivide` because the method `ButtonDivide_Click` is specified as a handler for `ButtonPlus`. You need to change the `Handles` clause. When you fix that, you'll probably get the same error from both operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this assuming you want "" to convert to 0

```
Dim val1 As Double

If Not Double.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, val1) Then
   val1 = 0
End If
```

I think, my VB is rusty.

PS you'll do yourself a lot of favours by picking up the .net side of things instead of relying on legacy VB6 stuff like CDbl etc.

Comment: "Value of type 'System.Windows.Forms.TextBox' cannot be converted to 'String'."

That's what I get when I replace `If CInt(True) Then Val1 = CDbl(TextBox1.Text)` :/

Comment: `TryParse` needs to reference `TextBox1.Text` instead of just `TextBox1`. Given a string, `TryParse` attempts to convert it to a `Double`. If it cannot due to invalid characters, it return `False`. If successful, it returns `True`.